# sql select query from two different tables WHERE active=1

Tags: mysql, database

*i try select all columns from two different tables WHERE active = 1*

i have 2 tables **table_pro** and **table_basic**,

> `sql:"select * from table_basic,table.name";`
>
> and 2 condition:
>
> 1. WHERE  active = 1
> 2. WHERE table_pro.id = table_basic.name.id

***how to make it correctly***

Here is table_pro

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
| id | people | rooms   |  active   | 
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
|  1 |      5 |      10 | 0         |
|  2 |     12 |      17 | 0         |
|  3 |     21 |      38 | 1         |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Here is table_basic

```
+---------+-------+---------+------------+----------+
| name_id | name  | balance | title      |  time    |
+---------+-------+---------+------------+----------+
|  1      |shop   | 100     | failed     | 15:10:20 |
|  2      |factory| 75      | error      | 15:10:20 |
|  3      |studio | 25      | timed_out  | 15:10:20 |
+---------+-------+---------+------------+----------+
```

I'd like to have this output result only rows (from of all columns) with status active = 1

```
+-----+-------+----- --+--------+-------+----------+---------+--------+
| id  | people| rooms  | name   |balance| title    | time    | active |           
+-----+-------+--------+--------+-------+----------+---------+--------+
|  3  | 21    | 38     | studio |25     | timed_out| 15:10:20|    1   |
+-----+-------+--------+--------+-------+----------+---------+--------+
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected result?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_pro p INNER JOIN table_basic b ON (p.id = b.name_id) WHERE p.active = 1;`

Comment: it seems like you could just combine these tables into one, no reason to keep them apart if they have a 1 to 1 relation

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I updated my question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.id, A.people, A.rooms, B.name, B.balance, B.title, B.time, A.active 
FROM 
    table_pro AS A
JOIN 
    table_basic AS B
ON 
    A.id = B.name_id
WHERE 
    A.id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_pro.*, table_basic.*
FROM table_pro
INNER JOIN table_basic
    ON table_basic.name_id = table_pro.id
WHERE table_pro.active = 1
```